# The meaning of 'in, out' in generic delegate declaration

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

```
public delegate TOutput Converter<in TInput, out TOutput>(TInput input)
```

What is the meaning of `in` and `out` in this declaration?

Comment: You might want to [take a look here and read the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) about the covariance and contravariance in generics in C#.

Comment: [Covariant and contra-variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: These are `Generic` modifiers. [`out (Generic Modifier)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) - [`in (Generic Modifier`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great article from Eric Lippert's blog that explains the in and out keywords.  They're used to express Covariance and Contravariance in generic type parameters.

[What's the difference between covariance and assignment compatibility?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx)

He also did a great 11 part series of articles on Covariance and Contravariance before it became a feature of C# 4.  I'd highly recommend reading them as they will really help you grasp the concepts.

I've just checked and they're not linked to each other (and there's no easy way to just link to the series that I can find), so here's a table of contents.

## Covariance and Contravariance in C#

- [Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx)
- [Part Two: Array Covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)
- [Part Three: Method Group Conversion Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx)
- [Part Four: Real Delegate Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/22/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-four-real-delegate-variance.aspx)
- [Part Five: Higher Order Functions Hurt My Brain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/24/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-higher-order-functions-hurt-my-brain.aspx)
- [Part Six: Interface Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/26/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-interface-variance.aspx)
- [Part Seven: Why Do We Need A Syntax At All?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/29/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-seven-why-do-we-need-a-syntax-at-all.aspx)
- [Part Eight: Syntax Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/31/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-eight-syntax-options.aspx)
- [Part Nine: Breaking Changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/02/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-nine-breaking-changes.aspx)
- [Part Ten: Dealing With Ambiguity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/09/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-ten-dealing-with-ambiguity.aspx)
- [Part Eleven: To infinity, but not beyond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/07/covariance-and-contravariance-part-twelve-to-infinity-but-not-beyond.aspx)